# What are the 3 types of JavaDocs for Groovy 1.8?

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

The Groovy 1.8 docs have 3 types of JavaDocs:

api/
  gapi/
  jdk/

The jdk/ Javadocs show methods that Groovy adds to Java classes.  That's easy to understand.

The JavaDocs in api/ and gapi/ are confusing.  They are similar except that api/ has a case-insensitive display of All Classes while gapi/ has a case-sensitive display of All Classes.  (The case-sensitive display makes it hard to find things.)

The gapi/ All Classes list has four genXXX entries at the end of the list (that case-sensitive sort again) which don't seem to be in the api/ list.

Does anyone know what the difference is between the api/ and gapi/ JavaDocs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Quoted from [Paul King on the Groovy User](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Exact-differences-between-html-api-html-gapi-and-html-groovy-jdk-td358407.html) mailing list

> "api" is the result of running javadoc
>   across all of the Java files.
>
> "gapi" is the result of running
>   groovydoc across all of the Java and
>   Groovy files. (Historically this was
>   just the Groovy files but it now runs
>   across both. If Groovydoc was finished
>   we could remove "api" altogether but
>   at least as of now, javadoc has more
>   information in it so we keep both.)
>
> "groovy-jdk" is run across just the
>   "category" files like
>   DefaultGroovyMethods and instead of
>   reporting the Javadoc across the
>   source file reports them across the
>   classes which the category extends.
>   E.g.:
>
> DGM#join(Collection self, String
>   separator)
>
> will be reported as:
>
> java.util.Collection#join(String
>   separator)
>
> which is how it appears to the
>   language user.

Comment: Ugh.  We need one set of docs that is comprehensive.  The GroovyDoc gapi should be best, but that case-sensitive display is a problem.